# Why do I get "Permission Denied"

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I want to write a file in the Documents folder of my iPhone app.
But when I try to open the path I get the

> Cocoa error 257 - Permission Denied.

Here's a little code snippet:

```
// create path to file
NSURL *path = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", [path description]);

NSError *error = nil;
NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", error);
NSLog(@"%@", [filename description]);
```

Can you tell me please, what's wrong with that code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you're trying to open the documents directory rather than a file in that directory. `stringWithContentsOfURL` loads the contents of the file into the `NSString`, so it's not a filename.

If `filename` should be a *path* rather than the contents of a file, use `stringWithContentsOfURL:` instead.